# Action of Torus on Grassmanian - a Highest Weight Description, or otherwise intrinsic description

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, algebraic-groups, grassmannian

What is an intrinsic description of the action of the Torus on the Grassmanian = $GL(n)/P$, where $P$ is a certain parabolic subgroup?

The explicit description in terms of the Plücker embedding I know is that the torus acts on the Stiefel manifold by acting on the column vectors; this action descends to one on the image of the Plücker embedding - i.e. of the Grassmanian.

Is there a highest weight description of the action?

Comment: Presumably the action is by left multiplication. What exactly is the question?